# Django rest_framework 3.22 multiple updates creating objects instead of updating

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have an API which needs to return a QuestionQueue and its associated Question objects as a list. I got it to work nicely and it returns the data how I want it:

```
class QuestionQueueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions = QuestionSerializer(
        many=True,
        source='question_set',
        required=False,
    )
```

I am having trouble getting updates to work on this API. I am following the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-update) for multiple writes. I have my own custom `ListSerializer` instance called `QuestionListSerializer`. Here's how I use it within the `QuestionQueueSerializer`:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    questions_data = validated_data.pop('question_set')
    super(QuestionQueueSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
    question_list_serializer = QuestionSerializer(
        instance=instance.question_set.all(),
        data=questions_data,
        many=True
    )
    if question_list_serializer.is_valid():
        question_list_serializer.save(
            company_id=instance.company_id,
            question_queue_id=instance.id
        )
    return instance
```

Here's the update method on the `QuestionListSerializer`, which I have set as the `list_serializer_class` on my `QuestionSerializer`:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    questions_by_id = {_question.id: _question for _question in instance}

    # Perform creations and updates.
    ret = []
    for question_data in validated_data:
        question = None
        if 'id' in question_data:
            question = questions_by_id.get(question_data['id'], None)
        if not question:
            ret.append(self.child.create(question_data))
        else:
            ret.append(self.child.update(question, question_data))

    question_ids_to_delete = set(questions_by_id.keys()) - {_q.id for _q in ret}
    Question.objects.filter(id__in=question_ids_to_delete).update(delete_ts=timezone.now())

    return ret
```

The problem is that when my `QuestionListSerializer`'s `update` method gets called, the `validated_data` does not contain the IDs of the questions. They all look like they are being newly created. The questions in the `request.data` all have IDs. They get stripped out somewhere along the way. I don't know how to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `id` fields are `read_only=True` in DRF's `ModelSerializer` hence they are dropped in the validation cycle. Making update to work requires more work. I had to do something similar for [DRF-bulk](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk) and the solution I ended up turned out was to create a serializer mixin which would put the id back. You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk/blob/master/rest_framework_bulk/drf3/serializers.py#L14-L32). Also I have some additional information in the [README](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk/blob/master/README.rst).

In case the code gets moved or something like that, here is the copy-paste of the serializer mixin:

```
class BulkSerializerMixin(object):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        ret = super(BulkSerializerMixin, self).to_internal_value(data)

        id_attr = getattr(self.Meta, 'update_lookup_field', 'id')
        request_method = getattr(getattr(self.context.get('view'), 'request'), 'method', '')

        # add update_lookup_field field back to validated data
        # since super by default strips out read-only fields
        # hence id will no longer be present in validated_data
        if all((isinstance(self.root, BulkListSerializer),
                id_attr,
                request_method in ('PUT', 'PATCH'))):
            id_field = self.fields[id_attr]
            id_value = id_field.get_value(data)

            ret[id_attr] = id_value

        return ret
```

Comment: I tried copying this code into my codebase but I could not get it to work. I tinkered left and right to no avail. On some invocations of `to_internal_value`, the` context` does not contain a `view`. If the root is an instance of my list, it does not contain `fields`. I am ready to give up on rest_framework altogether as it is exceedingly difficult to make it do what I need.

Comment: If root is a list, it will not contain any fields. `root.child.field` will exist though. `ListSerializer` does not contain any fields. All the fields fallback to the child serializer fields.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with tomchristie on IRC. Adding an explicit id field in my serializer and making it not read_only solved the issue.